# I can't share individual windows during skype/GoogleMeet video calls (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: screen, skype, sharing

During video calls, Skype and Google Meet only let me share the whole screen (desktop) rather than specific windows. The only option it shows is the Desktop screen as if I didn't have any other windows available to share. I'd appreciate it if you could give me a hand, as I give online classes through video calls, and not being able to share individual windows during them it's quite annoying.

Comment: I'm using Xorg, as it let me at least share the desktop screen. Using Wayland, the ''Share Screen'' option is not even available on Skype. The thing is, I would like to share specific windows screens and not only the general desktop one.